# How to open "Project structure" in CLion?

Tags: clion

How can I open "Project structure" in CLion? It's [supposed to](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html) be under "File", but it's not. There's also a keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, but that doesn't work either.